# WPF C# custom panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I want to create a user control which would work the same way as a classic Panel (or Canvas rather) control expect that I want to have there some default Buttons which the user won't be able to remove.

I tried this:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class CustomPanel : Canvas
    {
        public CustomPanel()
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Name = "Button1";
            b.Content = "Button1";
            this.Children.Add(b);
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but when I compile it and create an instance of CustomPanel in the designer and then try to insert another item the Button created in constructor gets deleted.

Is this the correct approach at all or is there a better (more effective/elegant) way then modfying the constructor?

Thanks in advance for any efforts.

Comment: Are you sure the button created in the ctor got deleted? Or did the new children just lay over the old one? Please also post the code where you add the second item.

Comment: Yes it got deleted. I don't add the second item in code I do add it in the designer, so after I have added the second item it looks like this:
<local:CustomPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="158,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
            <Button Content="Button" Canvas.Left="49" Canvas.Top="24" Width="75"/>
</local:CustomPanel>

Comment: I tried both ways (adding button in code and designer) and in both cases the new button didnt delete anything, it just layed over the old one.

Comment: If you solved your problem by yourself, please post the correct solution and mark it as answer, so that people with the same problem can benefit from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you add the Button to the **Children** object, in the constructor, and then replace the whole **Children** object when you instance it in XAML.
I'm guessing your XAML looks like this:?

```
<wpfApplication3:CustomPanel>
   <Button Content="New b"/>
</wpfApplication3:CustomPanel>
```

If you initiate it like this instead, you'll see that the button stays in place.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    CustomPanel p = new CustomPanel();
    p.Children.Add(new Button(){Content = "T"});
    gr.Children.Add(p);
}
```

What you can do to avoid this is this:

```
public CustomPanel()
{
    Initialized += OnInitialized;
}

private void OnInitialized(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var b = new Button { Name = "Button1", Content = "Button1" };
    Children.Insert(0,b);
}
```

Now you wait until the XAML have replaced the Children object, before you add your button.

Comment: I tried to copy-paste the code but unfortunately it doesn't work for me - I mean when I compile it and add CustomPanel user control to a window and then add to the CustomPanel another Button the first one gets still deleted.

Comment: I tried both. Anyway I've just figured out how to fix the problem. Thanks for the help.